# c# MongoDB lacked sufficient buffer space or because a quee was full

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, akka.net

I create Akka console application (http://getakka.net/) with c# language using database mongoDB 3.x, Driver mongoDB 2.1.1.5, application connect to localhost mongoDB.

throw error if too many request handle in 2hrs.

"Unhandled Exception : MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occured while opening connection to server ---> System.net.socket.socketExceptiom: An Operation on a socket could not be perfomed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a quee was full as system.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoMultipleAddressConnectCallback

there are bugs with MongoDB drivers?
or 
is there any database settings are still not optimized ?
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/parameters/

Advice me please.

Thanks

Comment: Please update your post with errors you got. Image is not readable.

Comment: What operations are you performing? Read/write? Are you freeing up connection after operation completion? Please share your minimum viable and testable code.